# umbraco: Control access to dashboard areas

Tags: umbraco

I've setup several areas in the dashboard.config file of my umbraco site to extend the admin.  However, not all users should have access to these tabs.  Is there a way to restrict access?  I can only see how to restrict access from a particular section (e.g. Settings or Developer).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well yes, its not possible to block certain tabs from the users section
you can workaround that yourself in the usercontrols on the dashboard itself.

in the page_load of your usercontrols you can request the current user 
and do something with it...

example: you could create a new usertype to give them access...

```
User u = User.GetCurrent();
if(u.UserType.Id != <the id of your new usertype>)
{
pnlNoAccess.visible = true;
}
```

there is a better solution beeing worked on,
[codeplex work item for this issue](http://umbraco.codeplex.com/WorkItem/View.aspx?WorkItemId=23256)
yet still it has no target for release.